# Springfox doesn't generate model description

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I'm using Swagger via Springfox in my Spring Boot application:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}
...
...
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-schema:3.0.0'
```

```java
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.x"))
            .paths(any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(
                    new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Title").build()
            );
}
```

Annotation over main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Main {
```

And, the DTO:

```java
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Valid
@Schema(description = "User profile")
public class ProfileDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 1, value = "User name")
    @Schema(description = "User name", required = true) //just another approach
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
```

But as a result there are no field description in Swagger UI, only the name of the DTO:

```
 ProfileDto{
 }
```

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**: I found that the description is **generated** when I'm running the application in the DEBUG mode in IntelliJ IDEA.